# Run SQL Server Update Statement With Powershell

Tags: powershell

Should be straight forward, but I keep getting this error

> shipping_status is not a recognized function name

And this is my syntax - what is causing this, as my statement will run issue free in SSMS

```
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.Connection=New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlCmd.Connection.ConnectionString='Server=Server1;Database=DB1;Integrated Security=True'
$SqlCmd.Connection.Open()
$SqlCmd.CommandText="UPDATE firefly.light.dbo.shipped SET shipped = 'Yes' WHERE shipping_status IN ('Loading', 'Shipped') "
$SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me but maybe try escaping the single quotes with a grave-accent(`):

```
$SqlCmd.CommandText="UPDATE firefly.light.dbo.shipped SET shipped = `'Yes`'
```

etc

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `shipping_status` actually exists in `firefly.light.dbo.shipped`, I'd try using an alias:

```
UPDATE s
SET shipped = 'Yes'
FROM firefly.light.dbo.shipped s
WHERE s.shipping_status IN ('Loading', 'Shipped');
```

There may also be a parsing issue since you're using double-quotes.  Try using Powershell here-strings:

```
$SqlCmd.CommandText = @'
UPDATE s
SET shipped = 'Yes'
FROM firefly.light.dbo.shipped s
WHERE s.shipping_status IN ('Loading', 'Shipped');
'@;
```

That has the advantage of not needing to escape your query with backticks.

If none of that works, you can always expand the `IN` expression into a list of `OR` expressions.